# Infinite loop when getting a line with getchar()

Tags: c, kernighan-and-ritchie

I was trying an exercise from K&R (ex 1-17), and I came up with my own solution.
 The problem is that my program appears to hang, perhaps in an infinite loop. I omitted the NUL ('\0') character insertion as I find C generally automatically attaches it to the end of a string (Doesn't it?).

Can somebody please help me find out what's wrong?

I'm using the GCC compiler with Cygwin on win8(x64), if that helps..

**Question -** *Print all input lines that are longer than 80 characters*

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define MINLEN 80
#define MAXLEN 1000

/* getlin : inputs the string and returns its length */
int getlin(char line[])
{
    int c,index;

    for(index = 0 ; (c != '\n') && ((c = getchar()) != EOF) && (index < MAXLEN) ; index++)
        line[index] = c;

    return (index);                                                                     // Returns length of the input string
}

main()
{
    int len;
    char chArr[MAXLEN];

    while((len = getlin(chArr))>0)
    {
        /* A printf here,(which I had originally inserted for debugging purposes) Miraculously solves the problem!!*/
        if(len>=MINLEN)
            printf("\n%s",chArr);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _"as I find C generally automatically attaches it to the end of a string"_ where did you find ?

Comment: On problem in your code: in `getlin`, first time you test `c != '\n'`, there `c` is uninitialized, and will have unpredictable value, which could well be exactly `'\n'`. Initialize it when you declare it (that is mostly a good idea to do *always* when declaring a variable, to avoid bugs like this).

Comment: Thank you so much, kind sir -- that solved the problem completely..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> And I omitted the null('\0') character insertion as I find C generally automatically attaches it to the end of a string (Doesn't it?).

No, it doesn't. You're using `getchar()` to read input characters one at a time. If you put the chars in an array yourself, you'll have to terminate it yourself.

The C functions that return a string will generally terminate it, but that's not what you're doing here.

Your input loop is a little weird. The logical AND operator only executes the right-hand-side if the left-hand-side evaluates to false (it's called "short-circuiting"). Rearranging the order of the tests in the loop should help.

```
for(index = 0 ; (index < MAXLEN) && ((c = getchar()) != EOF) && (c != '\n'); index++)
    line[index] = c;
```

This way, `c` receives a value from `getchar()` *before* you perform tests on its contents.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.. However, the program runs fine without the \0 at the end of the array.. 

It is when I enter a sentence less than 80 characters that the program hangs.. Even adding a null at the end of the string does not help.. Any ideas, sir?

Comment: @Somu I've edited, making a suggestion about the loop condition.

Comment: Thanks again.. It worked.. thanks a lot.. seems like I was doing a lot of things wrong..

Comment: You're welcome. If this solves the problem, you can click the checkmark to accept the answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

1) C doesn't add a final `\0` to your string. You are responsible for using an array of at least 81 chars and puting the final `\0` after the last character you write in it.

2) You're testing the value of `c` before reading it

3) Your program doesn't print anything because printf uses a buffer for I/O which is flushed when you send `\n`. Modify this statement to print a final `\n`:

```
printf("\n%s",chArr);
```

to become:

```
printf("%s\n",chArr);
```

4) To send an EOF to your program you should do a `Ctrl+D` under unix and I don't know if it's possible for windows. This may be the reason why the program never ends.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not positive about what's wrong, but you don't provide the input to the program so I'm guessing.

My guess is that in getlin your variable c gets set to '\n' and at that point it never gets another character. It just keeps returning and looping.

You never SET c to anything inside your getlin function before you test it, is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

C does not insert a NUL terminator at the end of strings automatically. Some functions might do so (e.g. snprintf). Consult your documentation. Additionally, take care to initialize all your variables, like `c` in `getlin()`.